# django admin don't show primary key in forms

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using django 1.4. I have a primary key filed called `city_id`. when i go to add a new record in django admin, it asks me to enter the primary key. why is it doing so.

```
class CityMaster(models.Model):
    city_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: You need a auto-increment primary key for your id field? If that's the case then django will automatically add that id column, you needn't declare it in the model .

Comment: You don't need to set the primary key. Django automatically add the primary key if you don't provide one, which can be accessed either as `id` or `pk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a primary key. If you want Django to handle this value for you then use an [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields).

```
city_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do so, it means no automatic key will be provided by django which is why you have to provide it by hands.